# How can I reduce the signature of a ECDSA for software product keys? C#

Tags: c#

This is my first post, as this is driving me mad!

I am using Bouncy Castle and Visual C#.

I have managed to use custom code that allows me to use a SecP112r1 curve/key size for a ECDSA key in Bouncy Castle.

I am using this to generate ECDSA signed product licence keys and my "raw" licence data consists of 6 bytes of data.

I take the 6 bytes and sign them with the above 112 bit ECDSA key.

I then encode the signature+licence data into a Base32 product licence key, however, my licence key is still far to long.

I know that many companies produce 25-30 character products keys, but mine is currently 66 characters at Base 32, which is far to long.

What am I missing. Surely I cant go lower than ECDSA 112 and even if I could I cant see how I can create a product key of only 25 chars including the digital signature.

Please note the following 2 points.

1. I know that this licence system can be broken, security is not key here.
2. My product key must be asymmetric, it must utilise a signature from public/private keys.

How do other products achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance for any guidance.

I did read about "truncating the hash" but can not figure out how I can achieve this suing bouncy castle in c#,

Kindest regards,
Stephen

Comment: "What am I missing" -> could it be that most short product keys do not use cryptography?

Comment: Far too long? People don't care much about the length, as long as your software works. Consider the fact that many products use license file (a much larger bunch of text).